# Extractors in for vs extractors in assignment

Tags: scala

I have this doubt with extractors.

If I can do this:

```
val a :: b = List(1, 2, 3)
```

why I cannot do this:

```
val c = for ( a :: b <- List(1, 2, 3) } yield a
```

Comment: what do you expect the value of `c` ?

Comment: Why do you need `for` in the first place? `for` iterates over collection, you only need first element. `val c = List(1,2,3).head`? Your first pattern matching makes sense if you want to get both head and tail in one operation, but the second one drops `b`.

Comment: I need it for complex `for` sequences for querying json objects

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The translation of a `for-yield` expression in Scala (without using guards) is the `map` function. If you try and use `map` instead, it'll seem a little clear as to the quirk with the code:

```
List(1, 2, 3).map((x: Int) => ???)
```

When you `map` over a `List[+A]`, you project each value, one at a time. You don't have the entire list at your disposable inside the higher order function.

On the contrary, when using pattern matching on the list itself, the compiler will translate your first example into (after some cleanup):

```
def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
  private[this] val x$1: (Int, List[Int]) = List(1, 2, 3) match {
    case (head: Int, tl: List[Int])scala.collection.immutable.::[Int]((a @ _), (b @ _)) => Tuple2[Int, List[Int]](a, b)
  };

  val a: Int = x$1._1;
  val b: List[Int] = x$1._2;
  ()
```

Which is a pattern match on the `List[Int]`, matching the case of a head and tail. It's simply syntatic sugar for regular pattern matching, same as for-yield is syntatic sugar for a `map`. They simply do *different things*.

Comment: OK, I've understood.  What syntax would you use in a for?

Comment: @david.perez What do you mean by "what syntax"?

Answer (score 0):

After Yuval answer, I've understood why it doesn't work.

Equivalent syntax if interested in 1st value:

```
val first = for (a <- List(1, 2, 3).headOption) yield a
```